# Handlebars.js / JSON Parse: data parsed from json is not in order

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

I have json data which i am parsing it through handlebars.js 
But the output i am getting is not exactly in the same order as it should be in json. 
My Json code :

```
"RiskModel":{  
         "RiskModel":[  
            {  
                  "ScoreFactors":{  
                  "34":"Total of all balances on bankcard or revolving accounts is too high",
                  "12":"The date that you opened your oldest account is too recent",
                  "39":"Available credit on your open bankcard or revolving accounts is too low",
                  "04":"The balances on your accounts are too high compared to loan amounts"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
```

My HTML Code :

```
{{#arf.RiskModel.RiskModel}}
{{#each ScoreFactors}}
 <li>{{this}} </li>
    {{/each }}
{{/arf.RiskModel.RiskModel}}
```

My output is as follows:

```
THE DATE THAT YOU OPENED YOUR OLDEST ACCOUNT IS TOO RECENT
TOTAL OF ALL BALANCES ON BANKCARD OR REVOLVING ACCOUNTS IS TOO HIGH
AVAILABLE CREDIT ON YOUR OPEN BANKCARD OR REVOLVING ACCOUNTS IS TOO LOW
THE BALANCES ON YOUR ACCOUNTS ARE TOO HIGH COMPARED TO LOAN AMOUNTS
```

"12" value is displayed first then "34" value.

I don't know why.

May i know the reason ?

How can i fix this ?

Edited after converting to array as suggested: 
I am getting same output as earlier. 
[image: output after converting obj into array]

Comment: Can you restructure your JSON into "ScoreFactors":[{"Score": "12", "Text": "some text"},{...},{...}]?

Comment: @Chad i am getting this json from an ajax call.

Comment: @Chad how can i restructure the JSON. Can you help me out with that ?

Answer (score 0):

ScoreFactors is a javascript object with four properties "34", "12", "39", "04". Properties in javascript objects do not have any order, so somebody else might even get another order of the four sentences when iterating over the object with each.

- You need to use an array, which keeps the order intact:

  "ScoreFactors": [
            "Total of all balances on bankcard or revolving accounts is too high",
            "The date that you opened your oldest account is too recent",
            "Available credit on your open bankcard or revolving accounts is too low",
            "The balances on your accounts are too high compared to loan amounts"
         ]
- If you also need the number values, you have to use objects inside the array:

  "ScoreFactors": [
            { "num": "34", "text": "Total of all balances on bankcard or revolving accounts is too high" } ,
            { "num": "12", "text": "The date that you opened your oldest account is too recent" } ,
            { "num": "39", "text": "Available credit on your open bankcard or revolving accounts is too low" } ,
            { "num": "04", "text": "The balances on your accounts are too high compared to loan amounts" } 
         ]

  with
  `<li>{{num}} {{text}} </li>`

Comment: can you give me an example with js fiddle how can i change above json using array in handlebars.js ? 
i don't need number values.

Comment: this is not working. Please check the edited code and output

Comment: Changing "ScoreFactors" from being an object to be an array:
https://jsfiddle.net/veraee/fg4srjo5/5/